# In algebraic topology, for a function $f$ what does $f _\ast$ mean?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

In algebraic topology, for a function $f$ what does $f_{ \ast}$ mean?

I'm solving some exercises and this is something that's appearing, often relating to homotopic functions, and I'm not sure what it means. Does anyone know?

Comment: Usually it means the induced map on the fundamental groups.

Comment: Thanks for answering. How is that well-defined? The fundamental group is defined for a topological space and a point.

Comment: I'm guessing it doesn't matter what point as long as it's in Im(F). The well-defined should come from f's continuity. So if I understand correctly it just a map from f to the amount of counterclockwise loops f does around one of the points in its' image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a continuous function between topological spaces (with base points)
$$
f: (X, x_0) \to (Y, y_0)
$$
then you have the induced function between the fundamental groups:
$$
f_* : \pi_1(X, x_0) \to \pi_1(Y, y_0).
$$
This function is defined by 
$$
f_*([\lambda]) = [f\circ \lambda].
$$

The $\circ$ is composition of functions.

Recall that the [fundamental group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_group#Definition) is a set of (continuous) functions (loops) (the $\lambda's$) modulo [homotopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy). That is you have an equivalence relation on the set (of continuous functions)
$$
\{\lambda: [0,1] \to X: \lambda(0) = x_0 = \lambda(1)\}
$$
The equivalence relation is that $f\simeq g$ is there is a homotopy taking $f$ to $g$. When you mod out by this, you end up with a group (the fundamental group) where the elements are equivalence classes. Above, the induced function is defined on a representative, so you need to check that the definition is well-defined. That is, you need to consider what happens if you pick another representative.

That the above is well-defined comes from the fact that if $f\simeq f'$ and $g\simeq g'$ via homotopies, then $f\circ g \simeq f'\circ g'$ via the composition of the homotopies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the the function maps an element from the fundamental group of $X$ to and element of the fundamental group of $Y$? Is that why you used []? Because the are all the same modulo homotopy?

Comment: Also what does $f \circ \lambda$ mean?

Comment: @JohnH.: Yes, basically. The [] comes from the fact that we are talking about equivalence classes. Let me update the answer a bit on this.

Answer (score 3):

John has a good question. There is a tendency in algebraic topology to confuse a topological space and a topological space with a base point. Grothendieck wrote to me in 1983 in part: " both the choice of a base point, and the 0-connectedness assumption, however innocuous they may seem at first sight, seem to me of a very essential nature. To make an analogy, it would be just impossible to work at ease with algebraic varieties, say, if sticking from the outset (as had been customary for a long time) to varieties which are supposed to be connected. Fixing one point, in this respect (which wouldn't have occurred in the context of algebraic geometry) looks still worse, as far as limiting elbow-freedom goes!" But if $f:X \to Y$, then   $f_*$ could be a morphism $\pi_1(X,x) \to \pi_1(Y,f(x))$, or $H_n(X) \to H_n(Y)$.